# Creating lists of all possible combinations of the same length

Tags: c#, list, nested, combinations

I have a list of game objects, with more than 5 objects. I need to create one list with nested lists that account for every possible combination of those game objects. The nested lists need an exact length of 5. Order of objects doesn't matter. I'm open to other ideas beside nested lists if there's a better option, but I need to be able to change the length of the original game object list and create an however number of combinations. Real or pseudo code would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the nature of these objects? What's in them?

I would also suggest you show us what you've tried so far...

Comment: I'm really unfamiliar with this area of C# and I haven't even known where to start. I've had inefficient ideas (nested for loops, nested if statements) and thought to try IEnumerable but don't understand how it works. I haven't tried anything so far because I don't even know how to implement it